# Use methods inside Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, .net, task, parallel.foreach

I should use `Parallel.ForEach` loop, and inside there should be call to method.

```
Parallel.ForEach(myList, item => {  
   DoSomethingWithItem(item);
 }
);
```

Should that method be `Task` or whatever?

```
private Task DoSomethingWithItem(MyClass item);
```

Also, this method shouldn't have return type, but I have warning "not all code paths return a value". Tried to put `void` keyword but seems it doesn't go in same context with `Task` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Do not make it more complicated than it has to be.

```
Parallel.ForEach(myList, item => {  
   DoSomethingWithItem(item);
 }
);
```

is perfectly fine for `void DoSomethingWithItem(MyClass item)`.

Making it "more" async is overkill at best, counterproductive in the worst case.

Comment: Would it be problem if `DoSomethingWithItem` has few tasks that should perform?

`public void DoSomethingWithItem(MyClass item) {
   var tasks = new Task[3];
   task[0] = DoSomething1(item);
   task[1] = DoSomething2(item);
   task[2] = DoSomething3(item);
}`

Comment: The syntax of running multiple tasks in parallel is not correct, but generally speaking, yes, if your method wants to start multiple tasks and wait for all, that's fine.